# Ending/releasing an instance of a class in java

Tags: java, oop

So I am currently working on an IRC Bot, which uses run(String channel), which then starts an instance of Bot.class and adds it to the list of bots, so multiple bots on the same channel will occour.
So I am interested in how to end these instances when the software ends. I did a bit of research, but I only found how to end threads / runnables. So how can i do this?

Here is my code(with some bits not relevant cut out):

```
public class MainBot {

  static List<Bot> bots = new ArrayList<Bot>();

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      run("ifnotbot");
  }
```

...

```
  public static void run(String channel) throws Exception {
    Bot bot = new Bot(channel);
    bots.add(bot);
    bot.setVerbose(false);
    bot.connect("irc.twitch.tv", 6667, "oauth:ojbc6s5rsgtvccbjow9iilw6mrjq08");
    bot.joinChannel("#" + channel.toLowerCase());
  }
```

...

Comment: Java has automatic garbage collection. They will be collected when the JVM terminates.

Comment: Well I wish to terminate the instance of Bot, but not System.Exit(0); if thats what you mean

Comment: In basic terms, you cannot force an object to be garbage collected in Java. However, you can be *certain* that no object will be garbage collected while there still exists a reference to that instance within reach. That is, if you still have a reference to this instance anywhere (say, in a list or as a public static variable in some class) then it will never be collected. You can point these references all to `null` or to some other object, this will mark your object eligible for GC, but *when* it occurs is not guaranteed by the JVM.

Comment: You mean saying object = null?

Comment: where object is the instance of Bot(). I can use .finalize() aswell, it extends PircBot, if you are familiar with it.

Comment: I would recommend you read up on Garbage collection. I gave you a good overview but you'll need more details to make these decisions.

Comment: Can't you call a function (or add it first if not present) like bot.close() or bot.disconnect() ? You have all bots in the list.